# Magento 1.9 show 404 page for Product Feed Generator Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, 404-page

I'm using a free extension to generate product feed,
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-feed-generator.html

Everything works fine when I install the extension on a clean Magento installation 1.9.3.2

But When I install it on my Magento (1.9.3.2), which has many other extensions installed, on live site, it gives me a 404 page not found when creating product feed.

I don't see anything in log file. How can I find out what caused this 404 issue?

[image]

Comment: 404s in admin are usually caused by an ACL issue. If you have just installed an extension, logging out of admin and logging back in usually resolves the issue. Could you try that first?

Comment: I have logged out and logged in again. I've also cleared all cached on the site. It still show 404 page. but other extension works fine. And also if I install this extension on a clean Magento, then it's working.